# Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' minGW32-make error

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, glfw

I'm trying to compile a GLFW example code on Windows. If I type the command:

```
g++ main.cpp -Ideps/include/ -Ldeps/lib/ -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

Straight into Command Prompt then it compiles perfectly fine. However I'm tying to use a makefile, and when I do I get the following output.

```
g++ -g -Wall -Ideps/include/ -c main.cpp
g++ -Ldeps/lib/ -lglfw3_win32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -o main.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile_WIN32:8: recipe for target 'test.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [test.exe] Error 1
```

The makefile I'm using is

```
PROG = test.exe
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -g -Wall -Ideps/include/
LDFLAGS = -Ldeps/lib/ -lglfw3_win32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
OBJS = main.o

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OBJS)

main.o :
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c main.cpp
```

And I'm invoking it with the command

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile_WIN32
```

I'm relatively new to makefiles so I have no idea what the problem is, so any help would be greatly appreciated. My only guess would be that it's not the source code, given it compiles okay using the `g++` command, and also on my mac (hence the non-standard makefile name) using a similar makefile.

Comment: You need to define a `WinMain` function

Comment: Use -c to prevent g++ from trying to run the linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `-o $(OBJS)` when linking? This should be `-o $(PROG) $(OBJS)`. You are trying to override your main.o file instead of using it...

Edit: Also, you are not using the same commands when building without make, you use `-lglfw3` while in the makefile you use `-lglfw3_win32`.

Edit 2 (view comments): Sometimes it's necessary to put libraries flag after the target when linking, this gives:

```
$(CC)-o $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: I don't know, I was just changing things trying to get it to work.
However when I change it as you suggested I get new errors, undefined references to `glfwInit` and the like. That's a linker error yeah? Any idea why it wouldn't be finding the GLFW library file when using make, but building in one command works fine?

Comment: @Kieran Crayn You are not using the same commands when building without make, you use `-lglfw3` while in the makefile you use `-lglfw3_win32`.

Comment: I have two instances of the GLFW library, libglfw3.a and libglfw3_win32.a because I was wondering if the problem was in the library file. Building directly with g++ in the command line works with either *.a, but neither works with my Makefile

Comment: @Kieran Crayn Check environment in your shell is the same than in you makefile. Add following commands in your makefile before the linking command: `echo $(SHELL)` `echo $(PATH)` `where g++`. Compare with commands in your cmd shell `set Path`and `where g++`.

Comment: I found the issue was in the order I was calling the flags. Moving main.o before the library flags fixed the problem.

Comment: @Kieran Crayn, this is very true, I already got this problem once with another library.